# Print on NodeJS (Epson TM-T20 III)

Tags: node.js, thermal-printer, cups, epson

I want/try to print with nodejs on my epson thermal printer.
I use the lib: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-thermal-printer

Some details about the printer:
The printer is connected with usb.

```
TM-T20III:

              Product ID: 0x0e28
              Vendor ID: 0x04b8  (Seiko Epson Corp.)
              Version: 1.00
              Serial Number: 583741563238500000
              Speed: Up to 12 Mb/s
              Manufacturer: EPSON
              Location ID: 0x01110000 / 3
              Current Available (mA): 500
              Current Required (mA): 2
              Extra Operating Current (mA): 0
              1284 Device ID: MFG:EPSON;CMD:ESC/POS;MDL:TM-T20III;CLS:PRINTER;DES:EPSON TM-T20III;CID:EpsonTM00001002;
```

I am working on macOS. The printing with CUPS is working without any problems.

Do you guys have any ideas?

My tries:

- Named the printer to "testprinter" (in CUPS) and tried interface: "testprinter",  "printer:testprinter" and so one

Comment: Or is there a way with serial connection? But how i can i setup the baudrate or so?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.